# Woocommerce plugin - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, warnings

When I was in Hostgator server, it wasn't showing any warning. But when I tried to move the files to my friend's Godaddy Linux server, and when I accessed the site, am seeing the following warning at the top of the page.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-post-types.php on
>   line 169

I have the `WP-DEBUG` constant in wp-config file set to `FALSE`.

Also, tried adding a `php.ini` file with the following contents:

```
display_errors = Off
expose_php = Off
```

But not getting resolved. Any reason why it happens in Godaddy?

**EDIT**

Even updated the Woocommerce plugin to the latest version. But still no use.

Answer (score 0):

this mostly caused by PHP version so try to check which version of PHP you are using.

Comment: In Godaddy server, it is 5.3